# How can I draw polyline Between two location in Google Map using Android with marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image how can I draw this?

[image: I]
I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image I try to draw polyline between two locations on google map in android as shown in the image how can I draw this?

correct image but I cannot draw perfect how can I draw it

I try below code but it's not working

here is my code:

```
public void mSetUpMap() {
    googleMap.clear();

    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        str = AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary();
    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        shareUrl = AppUtil.itinerary.getShareUrl();
    Log.e("Ittt", "" + AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary());
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTexrViewText(str);
    poiList.clear();
    poiList = AppUtil.itinerary.getPoiList();
    List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (POI item : poiList) {
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new
                LatLng(item.getLatitude(), item.getLongitude()))
                .title(item.getName()).anchor(0.39f, 0.39f)

                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker
                        ((R.drawable.m2red), item.getName()))));
    }

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            ani.setDuration(2000);
            ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
            ani.start();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but what exactly is not working, what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score -1):

[check this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-polyline-and-markers-along-the-tapped-positions-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-arraylist/)  this example which show you drawing polyline and markers along the tapped positions

[check this too 2](https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points) this example shows that drawing route two points